# Find a value of the type $\infty - \infty$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Find the value:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}-\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}\right)$$

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us what you have tried, we may be able to help you finish the problem along those lines or to help you find and correct a fault, if there is one, in your reasonning.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\dfrac{1}{\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\dfrac{1}{\log(1+x)}=\dfrac{\log(1+x)-\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\log(1+x)}$

For $x=0$ we have the form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we apply L'Hospital.

With some work (that I leave to you) we achieve the solution $-\frac12$.